# Using an IN clause with table variable causes my query to run MUCH slower

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am using SSRS report whereby I need to pass multiple parameters to some SQL code.

Based on [this](http://www.codeulike.com/2012/03/ssrs-multi-value-parameters-with-less.html) blog post, the best way to handle multiple parameters is to used a split function, so that is the road I am following.

However, I am having some bad performance after following this.

For example, the following `WHERE` clause will return the data in 4 seconds:

```
AND DimBusinessDivision.Id IN (
    22
  )
```

This will also correctly return in 4 seconds:

```
DECLARE @BusinessDivisionId INT = 22

  AND DimBusinessDivision.Id IN (
    @BusinessDivisionId 
  )
```

However, using the split function such as below, It takes 2 minutes (which is the same time it takes without a `WHERE` clause:

```
  AND DimBusinessDivision.Id IN (
    SELECT Item FROM dbo.FuncSplit(@BusinessDivisionId, ',')
  )
```

I've also tried creating a temp table and a table variable before the SQL statement with the results of the table but there's no difference. I have a feeling this has to do with the fact that the values are not literal values and that SQL server doesn't know what query plan to follow, or something similar. Does anyone know of any ways to increase the performance of this?

It simply doesn't like using a table to get the values in even if the table has the same amounts of rows.

UPDATE: I have used the table function as an inner join which has fixed the issue. Any idea's why this made all the difference?

```
INNER JOIN
  dbo.FuncSplit(@BusinessDivisionIds, ',') AS FilteredBusinessDivisions ON
  FilteredBusinessDivisions.Item = DimBusinessDivision.Id
```

Comment: Using a function like that in the where clause is making it scan the entire table, which is why it would take about the same time as not using a where clause at all.

Comment: Are you using Ad-hoc sql in your SSRS dataset query or using a stored procedure?

Comment: Ad-hoc sql- not a stored procedure. See my update, I added it as an inner join and the performance is back to 4 seconds now.

Comment: Try using a stored procedure and a better version of split function [`XML Split Function`](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) .

Comment: @M.Ali- interesting results. I'm filtering for another business division which using the original string split function, it takes 39 seconds. Using the CLR and XML based one, it takes 1:39?! The split is literally splitting 1 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to play with:

- Try the non-performant query and add `OPTION (RECOMPILE);` at the end of the query. If it magically runs much faster, then yes the issue was a bad cached query plan. For more information on this specific problem, you can Google "parameter sniffing" for a more thourough explanation.
- You may also want to look at the function definition and toss a RECOMPILE in there too, and see what difference that makes.
- Look at the estimated query plan and try to determine the difference.

But the root of the problem, I think, is that you are reinventing the wheel with this "split" function. You can have multi-valued parameters in SSRS and use "WHERE col IN @param": https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337396(v=sql.105).aspx

Unless there's a very specific reason you must split a comma separated list and cannot use normal parameters, just use a regular parameter that accepts multiple values.

Edit: I looked at the article you linked to. It's quite easy to have a SELECT ALL option in any reporting tool (not just SSRS), though it's not obvious. Using the "magic value" as written in the article you linked to works just fine. Can I ask what limitation is prompting you to need to do this string splitting?

Comment: Ah what?! I'm never listening to a co-worker again- he said you couldn't! Just tried it and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Lock, which part of my answer solved your issue? RECOMPILE or getting rid of the split function?

Comment: The part about using SSRS no natively pass in multiple parameters. A co-worker said you can't do that and you have to use split functions. Sorry, wasn't clear enough in my last comment. Reading that article, it is talking about Stored Procedures specifically.. so I think that is where my confusion came from. I can understand not being able to pass multiple values to a store procedure... I incorrectly assumed it applied for a T-SQL script not contained within a Stored Procedure.